# GORM can not add or update child row

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I don't know where I went wrong here, I try to add 2 hasMany relations to my ticker struct but it always fails on updating the rows with the message "can not add or update child row, foreign constraint fails".

```
type Ticker struct {
TickerID           uint64      `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
Symbol             string      `json:"symbol" gorm:"uniqueIndex;size:191"`
PriceChange        string      `json:"priceChange"`
PriceChangePercent string      `json:"priceChangePercent"`
WeightedAvgPrice   string      `json:"weightedAvgPrice"`
PrevClosePrice     string      `json:"prevClosePrice"`
LastPrice          string      `json:"lastPrice"`
LastQty            string      `json:"lastQty"`
BidPrice           string      `json:"bidPrice"`
BidQty             string      `json:"bidQty"`
AskPrice           string      `json:"askPrice"`
AskQty             string      `json:"askQty"`
OpenPrice          string      `json:"openPrice"`
HighPrice          string      `json:"highPrice"`
LowPrice           string      `json:"lowPrice"`
Volume             string      `json:"volume"`
QuoteVolume        string      `json:"quoteVolume"`
OpenTime           int64       `json:"openTime"`
CloseTime          int64       `json:"closeTime"`
FirstID            int64       `json:"firstId"`
LastID             int64       `json:"lastId"`
Count              int64       `json:"count"`
Analytics          []Analytics `json:"analytics" gorm:"foreignKey:TickerRefer"`
Signals            []Signal    `json:"signals" gorm:"foreignKey:TickerRefer"`
}


type Signal struct {
SignalID    uint64     `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
Symbol      string     `json:"symbol" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_signal;size:191"` //gorm:"size:191;primaryKey"`
Timeframe   string     `json:"timeframe" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_signal;size:191"`
Type        SignalType `json:"type" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_signal;size:191"`
Value       bool       `json:"value"`
TickerRefer uint64
}

type Analytics struct {
AnalyticsID uint64  `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
Timeframe   string  `json:"timeframe" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_analytics;size:191"`
RSI         float64 `json:"rsi"`
SMA50       float64 `json:"sma50"`
SMA100      float64 `json:"sma100"`
SMA200      float64 `json:"sma200"`
LowerBBand  float64 `json:"lowerBBand"`
UpperBBand  float64 `json:"upperBBand"`
Symbol      string  `json:"symbol" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_analytics;size:191"`
TickerRefer uint64
}
```

```sql
[rows:0] 
INSERT INTO `analytics`
            (
                        `timeframe`,
                        `rsi`,
                        `sma50`,
                        `sma100`,
                        `sma200`,
                        `lower_b_band`,
                        `upper_b_band`,
                        `symbol`,
                        `ticker_refer`
            )
            VALUES
            (
                        '1d',
                        52.481731,
                        0.057222,
                        0.060852,
                        0.077816,
                        0.052366,
                        0.061234,
                        'LTOUSDT',
                        0
            )
ON duplicate KEYUPDATE `rsi`=VALUES
       (
              `rsi`
       )
       ,
       `sma50`=VALUES
       (
              `sma50`
       )
       ,
       `sma100`=VALUES
       (
              `sma100`
       )
       ,
       `sma200`=VALUES
       (
              `sma200`
       )
       ,
       `lower_b_band`=VALUES
       (
              `lower_b_band`
       )
       ,
       `upper_b_band`=VALUES
       (
              `upper_b_band`
       )
```

Comment: Try add `references:TickerID`.

Comment: getting the same errors when adjusting ticker struct to this 
 Analytics          []Analytics `json:"analytics" gorm:"foreignKey:TickerRefer;references:TickerID"`
 Signals            []Signal    `json:"signals" gorm:"foreignKey:TickerRefer;references:TickerID"`

Comment: I have written such code before [example](https://go.dev/play/p/r3sz-G0bBvo). I don't understand why your code doesn't work. How did you save `Ticker`?